# How to get the real time object level changes in apex?

Tags: apex, developer

I have an object called myObject__c and when I create a new field, I want to get the field's name on runtime in apex. How can we do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm).

For example:

```
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
    for(Schema.SObjectField field : fieldMap.values()){
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
        String label = fieldResult.getLabel();
        System.debug('The field label is: ' + label);
    }
```

Please see the [Schema Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_Schema.htm). If you'd like to access other field metadata, use a different method of the [DescribeFieldResult class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getByteLength).